# add custom module to a published dnn site

Tags: dotnetnuke-5

I have a client site as a published dnn website hosted on a local server in the organization's premises.

I have developed a new module using the source code that fetches data using a stored procedure.

This is what I did to transfer the changes to the live site
1. I created the stored procedure manually on the live sites DB,
2. I published the site and replaced the content of the website folder with my published site.
3. I added the new module in the live site using the "Module Definitions" option found under the "Host" menu

Everything works perfect in the development environment, but When I publish the site and do the update on the live server , the module returns no data as expected.

Can someone guide me through how to moves the stored procedure and my new published site to the live site.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating your module as an installable zip file including SQL for creating the stored prods and any other db changes required.

There are a number of tutorials around that will help with this and the templates build by Charles Nurse are a great help in getting your head around good practice. (http://www.charlesnurse.com)

In the mean time have you checked the permissions on the SP in the live database. That may well be your issue.

James

Comment: Hi James, I have checked the permissions  on the SP and everything looks fine but the problem still persists. Let me also quickly add that I do my module development in visual studio 2010 and using ms sql server 2005. Anymore ideas as to what the issue could be.

Comment: Sorry, was a guess are you sure the tables are identical ? did you deploy all the ell's. ( more guesses sorry )

Comment: Yes , they are. In fact when I execute the SP in the ms sql server on the live site it returns the expected data.